# Open GL ES line does not have an end point

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I have used the following lines of code to draw a line from point A to point B.

```
const GLfloat line[] = {
    0.0f, 0.0f, //point A
    2.5f, -1.0f,  //point B
};
glColor4f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, line);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 2);
```

But my problem is the line does not end at the point B. It passes point B and keeps drawing. So I get a line which does not have an end point. Any kind of help is appreciated.
Thank You.

This is how my whole function looks like.

-(void)popupCircles{

```
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);
glViewport(0, 0, backingWidth, backingHeight);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrthof(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.5f, 1.5f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glPushMatrix();
const GLfloat line[] = {
    0.0f, 0.0f,  //point A
    2.5f, -1.0f,  //point B
};
glColor4f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,1.0f); //line color
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, line);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 2);    
glPopMatrix();       

glPushMatrix();
const GLfloat line2[] = {
    0.0f, 0.0f, //point A
    -2.5f, -1.0f, //point B
};
glColor4f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,1.0f); //line color
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, line2);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 2);    
glPopMatrix(); 

glPushMatrix();
const GLfloat line3[] = {
    0.0f, 0.0f, //point A
    1.0f, 3.0f, //point B
};
glColor4f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,1.0f); //line color
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, line3);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 2);    
glPopMatrix();     
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, square);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glColor4f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glPushMatrix();
glScalef(trans, trans, trans);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
glPopMatrix();    
glPushMatrix();
glScalef(trans, trans, trans);
glTranslatef(2.5f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
glPopMatrix();
glPushMatrix();
glScalef(trans, trans, trans);
glTranslatef(-2.5f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
glPopMatrix();
glPushMatrix();
glScalef(trans, trans, trans);
glTranslatef(1.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
glPopMatrix();
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
[context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];
```

}

Comment: What do your projection and model-view matrices look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't specified projection and model-view matrices, then point B is outside the viewport, which is in the range [-1, 1] for both x and y dimensions.

**Edit (in response to amended question):** Point B is outside the bounds set by the call to `glOrthof()`, so the line *should* go off the edge of the viewport.

Comment: That must be the problem. I do not have much idea about open gl. Thank you for the feedback and I will study about model-view matrices and get back to you.

Comment: @thilok: I just read your updated question. The modelview matrix isn't the problem. See my amended answer.

Comment: Sir, I looked at glOrtho and glViewport documentation but still get the same problem. Can you tell me how should I change glOrthof() to fix this problem?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the call to `glOrthof()` you just need to understand the effect it has. You are setting the viewport's x-range to [-1, 1], and point B, with an x-coordinate of 2.5, isn't within that range. So the line isn't extending past B. B is outside the viewport. To fix it, you either have to set a larger viewport (increase the coordinate ranges you provide to `glOrthof()` or reduce B). Either choice will bring the end of the line into view, but I can't tell you which to choose, because I don't know what geometry you are aiming for.